# Artifactory OSS 7.38.10 - Not able to log in using default admin credentials

Tags: artifactory

I installed artifactory-oss-7.38.10 linux version on CentOS 7.5 by as per the instructions in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#114759846aa77ee5734e34d7b8d6fba728e7f646f
But the default admin credentials are working when I'm trying to log in.The exception thrown is "You are not authorized to view this page". Here's a screenshot.

[image]

There are no exception thrown in console.log or any access logs. The only I noticed I in access-security-audit.log in the **jffe@000** user has scope **applied-permissions/user** while **jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d** has been assigned to **applied-permissions/admin** . Not sure if this has any bearing to the access issue.

```
2022-06-14T20:28:03.522Z|78012d2cb781a6ca|UNKNOWN|UNKNOWN|jffe@000|jffe@000/users/admin|C|TKN|{"added":{"owner":"jffe@000","created":"1655238483520","expirationTime":"1655240283520","subject":"jffe@000/users/admin","scope":"applied-permissions/user","id":"4e45e576-4821-4ab2-bfcd-b20b5f971a25","type":"session","username":"admin"}}


2022-06-14T20:27:18.262Z|0917123dd65329d4|UNKNOWN|UNKNOWN|jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d|jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d|C|TKN|{"added":{"owner":"jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d","created":"1655238438261","expirationTime":"1655238558261","subject":"jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d","scope":"api:* applied-permissions/admin","id":"6a176062-ae04-45a5-803c-4cf9d46445be","type":"generic"}}
```

I tried adding bootstrap.creds as well, but looks like it is not supported in the latest version. Not sure what I'm missing here, any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Response to system health REST API --> **curl -s localhost:8082/router/api/v1/system/health**

```
{
"router": {
    "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
    "state": "HEALTHY",
    "message": "OK"
},
"services": [
    {
        "service_id": "jfac@01g5hwt4jaq9bj0epefqv01bdj",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "jffe@000",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "jfint@01g5hwt4jaq9bj0epefqv01bdj",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "jfmd@01g5hwth461bft877wsfdqdsb0",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "jfob@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    },
    {
        "service_id": "jfrt@01g5hwtsydhm7g0mmssaf61m1d",
        "node_id": "ip-10-xxx-xxx-x.ec2.internal",
        "state": "HEALTHY",
        "message": "OK"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Can you try and paste this line in the address bar: 
http://localhost:<port-number>/artifactory/api/system/version
Use the port number that opens up the web application.
When the username password promp appears, add the credentials. I would like to understand if for some reason the default credentials changed.

Comment: @Tom.A here's the output `{
  "version" : "7.38.10",
  "revision" : "73810900",
  "addons" : [ ],
  "license" : "Artifactory OSS",
  "entitlements" : {
    "EVENT_BASED_PULL_REPLICATION" : false,
    "SMART_REMOTE_TARGET_FOR_EDGE" : false,
    "REPO_REPLICATION" : false,
    "MULTIPUSH_REPLICATION" : false
  }
}`

Comment: Alright. it's a progress.. as it means that the default credentials are set and functional. (As this api is requires admin credentials)
Try opening the developer tools and perform a 'Empty cache and Hard Reload', hard press on the refresh button should open this while developer tools opened.
Try to navigate to http://localhost<port>/ui/repos/tree/General/, login page should appear. Write here if you are getting the same error as before.

Comment: @Tom.A Tried your recommended steps by clearing the cache and accessing the URL. It redirected to the log-in page, but with the default admin credentials, it threw the same error "You are not authorized to view the page".

Comment: I am suspecting an unhealthy service. There’s an additional REST api you can try: curl -s http://localhost:<port>/router/api/v1/system/health

I would try to restart the server. 
If I understood correctly, it’s a tar.gz installation?

Comment: The API didn't show any unhealthy host, the entry for router and services are healthy. I've included the API response in the original post. Just wondering if it's an issue with the current version and can we fall back to a previous version, unfortunately, I couldn't find a link to any OSS archive. Can you share one if available?

Comment: @Tom.A Tried using the latest version **jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.39.4-linux**, still seeing the same issue with login. Are there any installation steps not mentioned in the install doc --> https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory

Comment: @Shamik were you able to resolve this? I am also getting into same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it ended up being that the host where my browser was running had access to the http(s) port, but didn't have access to some other ports. I haven't entirely tracked down which ones, but when I allowed a bunch more ports, it started working.